# RxJS Map array to observable and back to plain object in array

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5, angular2-observables, fork-join

I have an array of objects from which I need to pass each object separately into async method (process behind is handled with Promise and then converted back to Observable via `Observable.fromPromise(...)` - this way is needed because the same method is used in case just single object is passed anytime; the process is saving objects into database). For example, this is an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    ...
  },
  {
    "name": "Anna",
    ...
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe",,
    ...
  },
  {
    "name": "Alexandra",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Now I have the method called insert `which` which inserts object into database. The `store` method from database instance returns newly created id. At the end the initial object is copied and mapped with its new id:

```
insert(user: User): Observable<User> {
  return Observable.fromPromise(this.database.store(user)).map(
    id => {
      let storedUser = Object.assign({}, user);
      storedUser.id = id;
      return storedUser;
    }
  );
}
```

This works well in case I insert single object. However, I would like to add support for inserting multiple objects which just call the method for single insert. Currently this is what I have, but it doesn't work:

```
insertAll(users: User[]): Observable<User[]> {
  return Observable.forkJoin(
    users.map(user => this.insert(user))
  );
}
```

The `insertAll` method is inserting users as expected (or something else filled up the database with that users), but I don't get any response back from it. I was debugging what is happening and seems that `forkJoin` is getting response just from first mapped user, but others are ignored. Subscription to `insertAll` does not do anything, also there is no any error either via catch on `insertAll` or via second parameter in subscribe to `insertAll`.

So I'm looking for a solution where the Observable (in `insertAll`) would emit back an array of new objects with users in that form:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Anna",
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Joe",,
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Alexandra",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Can't see any obvious error. It sounds like only the first promise is resolving. Are you sure the database supports multiple concurrent promises? What happens if you try it just with promises and `Promise.all`? (Also, in your first code snippet, you create a `storedUser`, but return `user` instead of `storedUser`.)

Comment: Thanks for great suggestion, fortunately there is no problem with concurrent promises. There was a typo in this example which I fixed now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To convert from array to observable you can use [`Rx.Observable.from(array)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-from).

To convert from observable to array, use [`obs.toArray()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toArray). Notice this does return an observable of an array, so you still need to `.subscribe(arr => ...)` to get it out.

That said, your code with [`forkJoin`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin) *does* look correct. But if you do want to try `from`, write the code like this:

```
insertAll(users: User[]): Observable<User[]> {
  return Observable.from(users)
    .mergeMap(user => this.insert(user))
    .toArray();
}
```

Another more rx like way to do this would be to emit values as they complete, and not wait for all of them like `forkJoin` or [`toArray`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toArray) does. We can just omit the [`toArray`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toArray) from the previous example and we got it:

```
insertAll(users: User[]): Observable<User> {
  return Observable.from(users)
    .mergeMap(user => this.insert(user));
}
```

As @cartant mentioned, the problem might not be in Rx, it might be your database does not support multiple connections. In that case, you can replace the [`mergeMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) with [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) to make Rx send only 1 concurrent request:

```
insertAll(users: User[]): Observable<User[]> {
  return Observable.from(users)
    .concatMap(user => this.insert(user))
    .toArray(); // still optional
}
```

Comment: Thanks! When I changed `forkJoin` to `from` and `mergeMap` + `toArray` things started working as expected.